# jQuery AJAX appending to Json return data "d:null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web-services

Hey all I am getting an odd return from my callback when using the AJAX POST method to call my webservice.

The webservice is sending the JSON back like this:

```
Dim ser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim strResponse As String = ser.Serialize(results)

Context.Response.Clear()
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString())
Context.Response.Write(strResponse)
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

The value of **strResponse** above is:

```
"[{\"Column1\":\"0589S2F\"},{\"Column1\":\"53699FNS\"},{\"Column1\":\"C38VVFD\"},{\"Column1\":\"LFD55F\"},{\"Column1\":\"2ERfG\"},{\"Column1\":\"0079\"},{\"Column1\":\"2054\"},{\"Column1\":\"054FGW\"}]"
```

And for some reason my ajax returns **200** **OK** yet still goes into the **ERROR** logic with an error message of:

```
ERROR: "[{\"Column1\":\"0589S2F\"},{\"Column1\":\"53699FNS\"},{\"Column1\":\"C38VVFD\"},{\"Column1\":\"LFD55F\"},{\"Column1\":\"2ERfG\"},{\"Column1\":\"0079\"},{\"Column1\":\"2054\"},{\"Column1\":\"054FGW\"}]"{"d":null}
```

Notice how it appends the **{"d":null}** to the end of my request... Where is that coming from since I am not sending anything like that back in the  **strResponse**???

My ajax request code:

```
var sqlQ = "SELECT TOP 50 LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(OID, ' ', ''))) FROM vwPSDAT WHERE OID != ''";

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType: 'json',
     url: 'http://zzzz/Service1.asmx/theQ',
     data: JSON.stringify({ qString: [sqlQ] }),
     async: true,
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log('done!');                  
     },
     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
     }
});
```

Comment: So.. I don't know about your question, but I'd like to note that passing SQL queries from the client is a terrible idea. There's nothing to stop the user from opening the console or using fiddler to send any arbitrary statement (like maybe `DROP TABLE vwPSDAT`) to the server.

Comment: When you use `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery automatically parses the response. You don't need to use jQuery.parseJSON`. This isn't the problem, though, because you're not going into the `success` function.

Comment: There must be some other part of the webservice that's writing `{"d": null}`.

Comment: You can only return one JSON object in a response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it would seem that I just needed to add **Context.Response.Flush()** before writing to the page.

```
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString());
Context.Response.Flush();
Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Once I did that everything was fine.

Comment: flush should be called after write

Comment: Rather it seems you changed to `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` and started using GET? Because this is not working for me

Comment: Didn't worked for me. After adding AddHeader I receive this "Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/" in postman

Answer (score 2):

Adding response.End() solved problem for me:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", res.Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(res);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of doing what **StealthRT** seas, you got some error appended to the data you need, and you can get rid of it by specifying the length of your response and limiting the output:

`Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString());`