# JSON string not captured properly when using angular $http.post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have used **$http.post** method while changing the dropdown values. Which will call asmx file method and i have returned json string. But in the **then** method not captured the JSON string it showing the below error.

> Error: [$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$http/baddata?p0=%5B%7B%22St_Id%22%3A1%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Shan%22%2C%22Grade%22%3A%22S%22%2C%22Native%22%3A%22London%22%7D%5D%7B%22d%22%3Anull%7D&p1=%7B%7D

How can i get rid from this issue,

**HTML:**

```
    <div>
    Select ID:
    <select ng-model="selid" ng-change="getStuData({{selid}})">
        <option ng-repeat="id in stuID" value="{{id}}">{{id}}</option>

    </select>
    <input type="button" ng-click="AddData()" value="ADD" />
    <br /><br />
    <strong> Student validation form:</strong><br /><br />
    <form name="stuForm" novalidate>
        <table class="studetail">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Student ID:</span>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="stuId" name="stuId" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Student Name:</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="stuName" name="stuName" ng-maxlength="10" required />
                    <span ng-show="stuForm.stuName.$error.required && !stuForm.stuName.$untouched">Student Name required</span>
                    <span ng-show="stuForm.stuName.$error.maxlength">Maximum exceed</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Grade:</span>
                </td>
                <td>   <input type="text" ng-model="grade" name="grade" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Native:</span>
                </td>
                <td>     <input type="text" ng-model="native" name="native" required /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>DOB:</span>
                </td>
                <td>     <input type="date" ng-model="native" name="native" required /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("firstCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    var getData = $http.get('GetData.asmx/GetAllId');
    getData.then(function (response) {
        $scope.stuID = response.data;
    });
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    };
    $scope.getStuData = function () {
        var student = $http.post('GetData.asmx/GetStuData', { ID: $scope.selid }, config);
        student.then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
});
```

**ASMX:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication_ng
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for GetData
    /// </summary>
    [ScriptService]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class GetData : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        [WebMethod]

        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void Details()
        {
            List<StudentDetails> details = new List<StudentDetails>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from St_Detail", conn);
                    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        details.Add(new StudentDetails() { St_Id = (int)reader.GetValue(0), Name = (string)reader.GetValue(1), Grade = (string)reader.GetValue(2), Native = (string)reader.GetValue(3) });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            this.Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(details));
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void GetAllId()
        {
            List<int> Id = new List<int>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select St_Id from St_Detail", conn);
                    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Id.Add((int)reader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            this.Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Id));
        }
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void GetStuData(int ID)
        {
            List<StudentDetails> stu = new List<StudentDetails>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from St_Detail where St_Id =" + ID, conn);
                    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        stu.Add(new StudentDetails()
                        {
                            St_Id = (int)reader.GetValue(0),
                            Name = (string)reader.GetValue(1),
                            Grade = (string)reader.GetValue(2),
                            Native = (string)reader.GetValue(3),
                            //  DOB = (DateTime)reader.GetValue(4)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            //this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            this.Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(stu));
        }

        public class StudentDetails
        {
            public int St_Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Grade { get; set; }
            public string Native { get; set; }
            // public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here **GetStuData** method returning the record as JSON string but in the $http.post does not get t properly. Did i anything missed?

Comment: Can you show us what the asmx file returns ? In firefox, hit F12 > Network > Click on the line where you can read "GetData.asmx"
In Chrome ctrl+shift+i > Network > Click on the line where you can read "GetData.asmx"

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:55938/GetData.asmx/GetStuData
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Payload:

{"ID":"2"}

Comment: And what is the response?

Comment: This:

[{"St_Id":2,"Name":"Raja","Grade":"A","Native":"England"}]{"d":null}

Comment: asmx file fully updated in above

Comment: I see. Whet if you try to call `Flush()` after `Write(...)` ? What would be the response

Comment: do you also get {"‌​d":null} when you call GetAllId?

Comment: @VolkanAkınPaşa i have called it on initial load by using $http.get method. This will give proper response to me. When i use $http.post method there is some problem.

Comment: Posible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550530/response-write-in-webservice

Comment: @Lamasse i have checked this too, this also not giving proper solution. so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`  after `Write()` ? source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085057/jquery-ajax-appending-to-json-return-data-dnull

Comment: I have just called any service endpoint which doesn't respond with JavaScriptSerializer and there is no issue. try what @Lamasse recommended

Comment: @Lamasse used your suggestions but the response.data shows like this 

[{"St_Id":1,"Name":"Shan","Grade":"S","Native":"London"}]

</pre></table></table></table></table></table></font></font></font></font></font></i></i></i></i></i></b></b></b></b></b></u></u></u></u></u><p>&nbsp;</p><hr>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

.......